# Excel formula required to concatenate data from 2 different sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

[image]i need excel formula for the following concept
i have two sheets where the product name is common

sheet 1
Product.    US quantity.   NonUS quantity
ABC.        4.               2
CBD.        4.               3
XYZ.        5.               7

Sheet 2
product.   country id
ABC.        1000. (US)
ABC.        1100. (NonUS)
ABC.        2000  (NonUS)
ABC.        3000. (NonUS)
ABC.        3300. (NonUS)
CBD.        1000. (US)
CBD.        1100. (NonUS)
CBD.        2000  (NonUS)
CBD.        3000. (NonUS)
CBD.        3300. (NonUS)

Now i want to concatenate the product id and quantity in sheet2
if the region is US then it should pick 4 from US quantity column in sheet 1 if non US then pick 2 from column NonUS Quantity from sheet 1, below mentioned is how the data should look like in sheet 2

ABC 4
ABC 2
ABC 2
ABC 2
ABC 2
CBD 4
CBD 2
CBD 2
CBD 2
CBD 2

Comment: Shouldn't CBD NonUS be equal to 3 instead of 2?

Comment: Yea correct, cbd should be 3

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that both list starts from cell A1, you might use this formula in Sheet2:

```
=LEFT(A2,3)&" " &VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!A:C,IF(RIGHT(B2,4)="(US)",2,IF(RIGHT(B2,7)="(NonUS)",3,"Unpredicted country id")),FALSE)
```

Report any question you have or bug you have encountered. If, according to your judgment, this answer (or any other) is the best solution to your problem you have the privilege to accept it ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)).